# Pivot MySQL Data

Tags: mysql

I wish I could change the schema but I'm tied to it, suppose I have the following tables

```
JanDataTable
FebDataTable
MarDataTable
ProductsTable
```

Where the first three tables have columns ID and Amount Sold.  Products table has ID and Product Name.

I need to somehow join these tables to get the following output

```
ID | Product Name | Amount Sold | Month 
01 | TV 1         | 23          | 1     <- JanDataTable
02 | TV 2         | 43          | 2     <- FebDataTable
03 | Toaster 1    | 72          | 3     <- MarDataTable
```

Where ID is the product ID.

Is just a query possible?

Comment: This design is unsustainable. For your own sanity, get yourself in a position where you can fix that or else abandon this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.product_part,s.*
from
(
select d.*, 1 as Month from jandatatable d
union
select d.*, 2 as Month from febdatatable d
union
select d.*, 3 as Month from mardatatable d
) s
join product p on s.Product_id = p.product_id
order by s.month, p.product_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up going with something similar to this

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Using `LEFT JOIN` to do it.

```
select 
    p.id as ID, p.`Product Name`,
    coalesce(jan.`Amount Sold`,0) + coalesce(feb.`Amount Sold`,0) + coalesce(mar.`Amount Sold`,0) as `Amount Sold`,
    case when p.id = '01' then 1
        when p.id = '02' then 2
        when p.id = '03' thwn 3
    end as Month
from ProductsTable as p
    LEFT JOIN JanDataTable as jan ON p.id = jan.id 
    LEFT JOIN FebDataTable as feb ON p.id = feb.id 
    LEFT JOIN MarDataTable as mar ON p.id = mar.id
```

Comment: Well, if you're determined to provide a solution, here's a hint: UNION